# How can I read a binary file and turn that data into an rgb image?

Tags: python, binary, python-imaging-library

I've got a .bin file. The data inside has has bit depth of 8, expecting RGB888 format, meaning 8 bits per channel. I'd like to reconstruct it as a.png file with its color intact.

I saw/tried working with this top answer: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763298/how-can-i-read-a-binary-file-and-turn-the-data-into-an-image)

When I tried running the above, my original image that was captured appears zoomed in. I can only ever get the full content of the original image captured when I multiply the count variable by 3 (count=w*h*3). Of course, I then have the width parameter multiplied by 3 too to match. Obviously, this is wrong in the sense that it results in a very large image. Furthermore, I still have my reconstructed image in grayscale.

As such, I want to know how I can take my .bin file and reconstruct it into a colored .png file.

Comment: You didn't share your bin file (use Google Drive or Dropbox or similar). Nor did you share its dimensions. Nor did you share your code. Please click [edit] and add all the information missing from your [mcve]. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't post the code or the .bin file as that is company owned. The dimensions are 5496x3672. Each byte is between 0 and 255. I was just hoping for a general idea for how I can approach reading .bin files and reconstructing them as RGB images rather than grayscale using Pillow.

Comment: One thing I'd like to know how is the count parameter in numpy.fromfile() impacted when color is involved? There seems to be some relationship when a color image has 3 channels and I get the full image only when multiplying the image dimensions by 3 as my count parameter. A grayscale image has one channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like this - be sure you have height and width set correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Define width and height
w, h = 5496, 3672

# Read file using numpy "fromfile()"
d = np.fromfile("YOURFILE.BIN",dtype=np.uint8,count=w*h*3).reshape(h,w,3)

# Make into PIL Image and save
PILimage = Image.fromarray(d)
PILimage.save('result.png')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I now understand that I had the reshape parameters wrong.