# Convert 32-bit image to 8-bit

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

My camera outputs images in 32-bit greyscale. I want to convert to 8-bit by keeping most significant 8 bits and dropping the rest. Does `Image.convert('L')` already do this, or is there a better way? Concern is to limit quality loss while converting.

Comment: What image format is the input? Can you give an example?

Comment: @NickODell input image is 32 bit monochrome as a PIL.Image, mode I ( (32-bit signed integer pixels))

Comment: Why would there be any perceivable loss of quality?  The human eye can distinguish about 200 shades of grey between black and white, so 8 bit will always be adequate for greyscale for presentation.  Image processing may benefit from the larger pixel representation avoiding loss of information through manipulation.

Comment: @Clifford The application here is a very precise spot detection with sub-pixel accuracy, so the fear was the conversion down to 8 bits may result in sub-optimal results.

Comment: Quite possibly; as I said 8 bit is adequate for  human presentation. Machine vision is a different matter.  But I would suggest that is a matter of loss if _information_, not loss of _quality_. One is mathematical, the other subjective.  Clearly you will loose information, but whether that matters depends on the purpose of the reduced image.

Comment: You might benefit from _companding_ a non linear encoding where you have smaller quanta for either darker or lighter shades.  It is used in audio (u-Law/A-law) for example where 8 bit values have an effective dynamic range of 13 or 14 bits.  That however relies on the principle that the psycho-acoustically important information tends to be in the quieter sections.  So you still loose information, but you loose it where it is less important.  Might be hard to apply generally to image processing

Comment: What camera make/model is it, please? Can you share a sample image - you can use Google Drive or Dropbox or similar. Please also share width and height.

Comment: @Clifford Most images are stored with a gamma function applied, which compresses the brighter values and expands the darker ones, much in the same way as you describe for audio. We’re more sensitive to small changes in dark regions of the image than in bright regions of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Three thoughts:

- Simply retaining the most significant 8 bits does not necessarily *"retain the most quality"*. What if you had a very dimly-lit object and all the pixels were in the range 0..255? They would all show up as zero whereas you had useful data before. What if you had a low-contrast object where all the pixels were in the range 16000..30000, they would also all go to zero and be less useful, or lower *"quality"*, than the low-contrast version.
- There are not many likely file formats (such as JPEG which is 8-bit, or PNG which is 16-bit, or TIFF which is likely float) that your unspecified camera without any available sample data would record in. So your data is most likely just a manufacturer-specified raw format. As such, you will not be reading it with PIL's `Image.open()` but far more likely with `np.fromfile()` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76830013/2836621) example. As such, you will have the data in Numpy and will be able to scale it however you wish before making it into a PIL Image, as such the question of what PIL does with 32-bit images becomes irrelevant because you will have already made it `uint16` or somesuch before PIL even sees it. See last part of answer.
- It seems PIL makes a mess of converting 32-bit integers into uint8 anyway from the following example.

---

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Make an array of int32 with range 0..512
na = np.linspace(0,512, 512, dtype=np.int32)

# Make that array into a PIL Image, then convert to 'L' mode (8-bit) then revert to numpy array
n8 = np.array(Image.fromarray(na).convert('L'))
```

The array `n8` now looks like this:

```
array([[  0],
       [  1],
       [  2],
       [  3],
       [  4],
       [  5],
       [  6],
       [  7],
       [  8],
       [  9],
       [ 10],
       [ 11],
       [ 12],
       ...
       ...
       ...
       [224],
       [225],
       [226],
       [227],
       [228],
       [229],
       [230],
       [231],
       [232],
       [233],
       [234],
       [235],
       [236],
       [237],
       [238],
       [239],
       [240],
       [241],
       [242],
       [243],
       [244],
       [245],
       [246],
       [247],
       [248],
       [249],
       [250],
       [251],
       [252],
       [253],
       [254],
       [255],
       [255],
       [255],
       [255],
       [255],
       [255],
       ...
       ...
       [255],
       [255],
       [255]]
```

---

As referred above, if you are reading a manufacturer's raw file, you will most likely use code like the following. I am showing how you can discard the least significant 3 bytes and retain the most significant byte:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Define width and height
w, h = 1024, 768

# Read file using numpy "fromfile()"
d32 = np.fromfile("YOURFILE.BIN",dtype=int32,count=w*h).reshape(h,w)

# Retain only most significant byte
d8 = (d32 >> 24).astype(np.uint8)

# Make into PIL Image and save
PILimage = Image.fromarray(d8)
PILimage.save('result.png')
```

Comment: One comment to this: TIFF can store 32-bit signed or unsigned integers. It can even store floating-point numbers. Whether you can find software that can read those TIFF files is a different question…

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, although the *"Sample Format"* tag (0153) that OP would need for signed 32-bit integers is not part of baseline TIFF, i.e. it is an extension.

Comment: Exactly. Which is why it’s hard to find a reader that will read those TIFF files. I’ve used them, DIPlib can read and write them, I’m sure there’s other scientific software that does.